# Jquery fadeout and fadein only once

Tags: jquery, html

I fadeout and fadein username  input below.

```
<p>
    <input type="text"> <span id="xxspan1" style="display: none">Username</span>
</p>


<script>
    $("input").focus(function () {
        $(this).next('#xxspan1').css("display", "inline").fadeOut(1000);
        $(this).next('#xxspan1').fadeIn(2000);


    });
</script>
```

i dont want to fadein and fadeout on focus second time.I only want fadeout and fadein only once(first) time.

What is the best way to do this ?

Comment: And, what do you want after first time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [One()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) for this purpose. It will attach the event to an element which will execute only once.

```
$("input").one("focus",function () {
        $(this).next('#xxspan1').css("display", "inline").fadeOut(1000);
        $(this).next('#xxspan1').fadeIn(2000);


    });
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xuh4c/7/)

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$("input").on("focus",function (event) {
    $(this).next('#xxspan1').css("display", "inline").fadeOut(1000);
    $(this).next('#xxspan1').fadeIn(2000);
    $( this ).off( event );
});
```